# Trying to draw 2 triangles

Tags: java, applet, awt, graphics2d

I am trying to create two triangles with one being upside down and on top of the other. However, the program is only painting the first triangle. What am I doing wrong?

```
   public class Triangle extends Applet {


  public void paint( Graphics g ) {

    int[] xPoints = {10, 260, 135};
    int[] yPoints = {250, 250, 10};
    int numPoints = 3;
    // Set the drawing color to black
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    // Draw a filled in triangle
    g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, numPoints );  

 }


    public void newTriangle( Graphics h ) {

    int[] xPoints2 = {135, 395/2, 145/2};
    int[] yPoints2 = {250, 130, 130};
    int n = 3;

    h.setColor(Color.white);

    h.fillPolygon(xPoints2, yPoints2, n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `newTriangle` anywhere? If not, there's your answer.

Comment: But I do not call paint anywhere either and it still draws the triangle.

Comment: `paint` is called by another class which knows about that method because it's declared in `Applet`. No other class has any knowledge of your method, it's brand new, so no one is calling it.

Comment: So how would I call it inside of that same class?

Comment: Look at my answer

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

`paint` is called by another class which knows about that method because it's declared in `Applet`. No other class has any knowledge of your method, it's brand new, so no code is calling it. If you want it to be called you'll have to do it yourself:

```
public class Triangle extends Applet {

  @Override   //this is good practice to show we are replacing the ancestor's implementation of a method
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int[] xPoints = {10, 260, 135};
    int[] yPoints = {250, 250, 10};
    int numPoints = 3;
    // Set the drawing color to black
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    // Draw a filled in triangle
    g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, numPoints );  

    newTriangle(g); //call your method
 }

 public void newTriangle(Graphics h) {
    int[] xPoints2 = {135, 395/2, 145/2};
    int[] yPoints2 = {250, 130, 130};
    int n = 3;

    h.setColor(Color.white);

    h.fillPolygon(xPoints2, yPoints2, n);
  }
}
```